# How to ensure that a route is triggered only after the previous route ends?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

`from("direct:"+CCUREConstants.ROUTE_SYNC_PERSONNEL)
            .routeId(CCUREConstants.ROUTE_SYNC_PERSONNEL).noAutoStartup() .log()).setProperty("currentTime").method() .bean() .bean() .setProperty().body() .bean() .noAutoStartup() .process(new Processor() { }) .bean() .setProperty().body() .bean() .bean() .log() //Under Test .autoStartup(true) .end()}`
I have situation where i want my previous routes of Apache camel to finish then it should trigger the same route again only.

Below is what I tried but unsuccessful.

I tried setting autostartup as false when route starts and set to true before it finish.

Comment: We cannot see what you have tried. You should update your question

Comment: .noAutoStartup()
   .log())
   .setProperty("currentTime").method()
   .bean()
   .bean()
   .setProperty().body()
   .bean()
   .noAutoStartup()
   .process(new Processor() {
   })
   .bean()
   .setProperty().body()
   .bean()
   .bean()
   .log()
   //Under Test
   .autoStartup(true)
                        .end

Answer (score 0):

is it "I have situation where i want my previous exchange or messages of Apache camel to finish" ?

Again to start the same route again - if the consumer endpoint uses polling then the route will start again from the beginning by picking new message and process.

However, based on my understanding answered below:
Regarding the route or context start refer [configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup](http://camel.apache.org/configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup.html)

You can also start and stop route at runtime

```
public class RunTimeRouteControl {

    private final String routeId;

    public RunTimeRouteControl(String routeId) {
        this.routeId = routeId;
    }

    public void stopRoutes(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.getContext().getInflightRepository().remove(exchange, routeId);
        exchange.getContext().stopRoute(routeId);
    }

    public void startRoutes(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.getContext().getInflightRepository().remove(exchange, routeId);
        exchange.getContext().startRoute(routeId);
    }
}
```

**Bean configuration**:

```
<bean id="runTimeRouteControl" class="RunTimeRouteControl" >
    <constructor-arg name="routeId" value="routeName"  />
</bean>
```

**In context**

```
<to uri="bean:runTimeRouteControl?method=stopRoutes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same situation in one of my application. I achieved it through using `startupOrder`. Using this one can able to define the order in which route has to start.

[Please Refer this link for more about start up order](http://camel.apache.org/configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup.html)

-Jay

Comment: Hi Jay,                                                                                                                 Startup order defines the order in which routes start for different routes only but in my case my route is same which scheduled to run after interval of time (CRON jobs) sometime I get a situation where same route is still in process and has not finished the task it again gets triggered which I need to synchronize(It should not start if same route is already running).

Comment: Manjeet, Got your problem. Please refer this site `http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html`

Comment: Hi Jay,                                                                                                                  If you can illustrate an example how to achieve this with Oncompletion.

Comment: I will explain how it will in spring DSL. You can have `<onCompletion>` tag with it keep the part of code which will run first and takes time to complete. This will prevent from starting route running again.